# Decimal number regular expression, no any . {dot or point } Using PHP

Tags: php, regex

For example if I had:

```
1.2
1.65
5
9.5
125
```

Valid numbers would be `5`  and `125`.

Invalid numbers : `1.2`, `1.65`, `9.5`

I am stuck in checking whether a number has a decimal or not.

I tried `is_numeric` but it accepted numbers with a decimal.

Comment: What? Could you clarify what you mean? Also please include a example and your expected output, also, have you tried something?

Comment: [ctype_digit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

Comment: *i want* Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Show us where you are stuck and we are happy to help

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to try using `strpos`:

```
if (strpos($a,'.') === false) { // or comma can be included as well
    echo 'Valid';
}
```

or try it using regex:

```
if (preg_match('/^\d+$/',$a))
    echo 'Valid';
```

Examples taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words).

Comment: `strpos()` won't work with an int, so you need to cast the ID to a string if you are gonna use `strpos()`. The variable might be a real int or float.

Comment: $a should be a string here. i have used `===` to compare types as well.

Comment: But we don't know if `$a` is a string, it could be anything. So you might want to add some code to make sure it is, or add checks if it's an integer or float.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the number variable is **not** a string you can use `is_int()` to check whether it is valid or `is_float()` to check whether it is invalid.

But if you handle forms for example the variable is often a string which makes it harder and this is an easy solution which works on strings, integers and floats:

```
if (is_numeric($number)) {
    //if we already know $number is numeric...
    if ((int) $number == $number) {
        //is an integer!!
    }
}
```

It's also faster than regex and string methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use `is_float()` function to find invalid numbers

Comment: Better to use `is_int` to find valid numbers :)